# StartAngle of Pie in Graph in Telerik reporting Q12013

Tags: telerik-reporting

I just want to ask a question about telerik reporting q1 2013. I'm going to render a Pie Chart using new feature Graph -> Pie Chart
the question is how can i change the Start Angle (usually existed in old version) of the pie chart in the new version?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This property is now available in the Q2 2013 release. AngularAxisStartAngle is a new property on the PolarCoordinateSystem object.

Select your pie graph, go to properties, in the Misc section you will have a CoordinateSystems property, drill into this property and you should see the polarCoordinateSystem for the graph. Set the AngularAxisStartAngle to the angle value you desire.